# Java: How to retrieve underscore characters in java

Tags: java, primitive

Hi guys i am working with primitive data types in java and facing with some problem. i learned that java accepts underscore characters combined with numeric.
so i tried to make a variable with those combination

```
 long card = 45_230_21L;
```

but when i print the card value it shows "4523021".
i don't have problem with that this time but in the future reference can i retrieve the same arrangement of the underscores(45_230_21) in my card value? thanks in advance

Comment: Store it as a string?

Comment: No, the compiler doesn't know the difference between `10` and `1_0`.

Comment: underscores here are used just to make it readable.. compiler sees it as a number without underscores.. if you want to store them anyway, use a String

Comment: Also this code does not compile for me, problem with the leading 0

Comment: thanks guys i have now an idea and also sorry for the bad example edited it know thanks all :)

Answer (score 0):

when you define `card` as `long`, the compiler stores and sees it as a long value, which does not include any characters apart from pure digits.
in the future, if certain format is needed, you can try to separate the digits out by using '%100' , '%1000' and etc. and + '_' and convert the digits into string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
String cardString = "45_230_211";
long card = Long.parseLong(cardString.replace("_", ""));
```